# media sideload image not working with JPG file

Tags: uploads, media

`media_sideload_image` function not working for image url with JPG extension, its working fine for jpg (http://example.com/image.jpg) and png (http://example.com/image.png) but not with JPG (http://example.com/image.JPG)

following is the error returned

```
[errors:WP_Error:private] => Array
        (
            [http_404] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Not Found
                )

        )

    [error_data:WP_Error:private] => Array
        (
        )
```

Comment: as far as i recall the filenames are case sensitive. means, if the picture is saved image.jpg it wouldnt be found as image.JPG

Comment: file is saved with JPG and I can access with with direct url

Comment: Why do you want to use uppercase extensions. Extensions are lowercase. In general, you should really really try to avoid special characters and uppercase lettering in file names. Somewhere along the line this is going to backfire as it did in your case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check for the special characters in url, sometimes url structures may contain special characters like space, &, ' .

use `str_repalce` to replace known special characters or `urlencode`.

media_sideload_image works properly with JPG as well so either url contains special characters.

If you can access image through url there is not a permission issue as well which blocks image download sometimes.